# php return after of string from one word

Tags: php, string

MY question is So simple.
i have this string:

```
$main = "this is my main string here that i want to cut it and return here !";
```

And my key is:

```
$key = "main";
```

Now, i want to have this output:

```
$output = "main string here that i want to cut it and return here !";
```

***I mean i want to have that output , from my main word till end of sentence!***

How can i do it with **PHP** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code.

```
$main = "this is my main string here that i want to cut it and return here !";
echo strstr($main , 'main');
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$str="this is my main string here that i want to cut it and return here !";
echo strstr($str, 'main');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$main = "this is my main string here that i want to cut it and return here !";
$key = "main";
echo substr($main,strpos($main,$key));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **strpos** you can find the first ocurrence of *$key* in *$main*:

```
$main = "this is my main string here that i want to cut it and return here !";
$key = "main";
$x = strpos($main, $key);
$result = substr($main, $x);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code :

```
$main="this is my main string here that i want to cut it and return here !";
echo strstr($main, 'main');
```

[For More Details:](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strstr.asp)

Answer (score 0):

`strpos` find first position of substring, 'main' in our case. It return 11, put it into $tmp. `substr` return part of our string `$main` from start to `$tmp` position. As result main string ***here that i want to cut it and return here!***

```
$main = "this is my main string here that i want to cut it and return here !";
$tmp = strpos($main, "main");

echo substr($main, $tmp);
```

Comment: A short comment explaining how the above works would greatly improve the answer.

Comment: `strpos` find first position of substring, 'main' in our case. It return 11, put it into $tmp. 

`substr` return part of our string $main from start to $tmp position. As result **main string here that i want to cut it and return here !**

Comment: @fejese - done, updated answer. I hope it will be useful for someone.